# fogbugz vs. OTRS

Tags: fogbugz, otrs

I'm looking for a simple solution for support case management. The final nominees are Fogbugz and the open source OTRS.

Answer (score 3):

Hai ofer,

I have used fogbugz for all my web application test cases... It has good version control which be very useful to graph your cases from the day of first test to the latest version....

Individual logins from admin and users would be best suited for assigning,reopening and closing cases....

FogBugz makes it simple to enter bug reports and other types of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Also a FogBugz user. I use it for:

- Integrating with SVN for Bugz update assignment to cases
- Have an email inbox set up (cases@xxx/fogbugz.com) to allow end-users to submit email (either via their email client or through automation)
- I use their API to allow bug submissions through our UI
- Managing my team. I categoriese something as "Design", and it goes to our designer

Along with the excellent filtering of cases which allows you to get a snapshot based on any criteria you can think of. It's also really good at concurrency, so if changes occur on a ticket while you're looking at it, you are notified.